# How to get BIP34Hash and nMinimumChainWork?

Tags: bitcoin-core, bitcoind, bitcoin-core-development

I'm interested in the technical question of how you got BIP34Hash and nMinimumChainWork.

The changes were introduced here:

nMinimumChainWork: https://github.com/bitcoin/bitcoin/commit/ad20cddce2097c6561202777fccd257deb1a9810

BIP34Hash and BIP34Height: https://github.com/bitcoin/bitcoin/commit/33c90cf197223fb95f858db80d090d570d70498a

Comment: You can run the rpc `getblockchaininfo` to get the current chain work. Consequently this is the minimum chain work, as the chain work can never decrease.

Answer (score 3):

The BIP 34 hash is the block hash at which BIP 34 was fully activated and all blocks less than version 2 were rejected as invalid.

`nMinimumChainWork` is a value that is updated at every release. It is retrieved from the `getblockchaininfo` RPC of a node that is up at the time of release. `nMinimumChainWork` is updated at the same time as `assumevalid`. It is calculated by summing the work done in each block which is calculated by doing `2^256/(target+1)`